# Python opens in script instead of python-3.9.5.amd64

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, jupyter-notebook, syntax-error

Up until now whenever I downloaded an ipynb file it would open in

`C:\WinPython\WPy64-3950\python-3.9.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\transutils.py:13`

and the old downloaded ipynb files still do, but the newer ones open in

`C:\WinPython\WPy64-3950\scripts>`

so I get an error saying: ".ipynb" cannot be processed syntactically at this point.

What can I do to fix this?

Note: I am using Windows 11

Comment: contents of the file ?  can you open an simple `hello world` file ?

Comment: @D.L the file is a Jupyter Notebook. I am able to open the Jupyter Notebook / Jupyter Lab that is installed in the WinPython package (and I am able to write and execute programs there), but I can't do anything with the downloaded one.